# Removing rows matching a condition after using them

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I've a df like this one but much larger:

```
        tfirst            tend             mean_light duration      inter
1  2016-12-10 02:40:03 2016-12-10 02:40:03          2       10         NA
2  2016-12-14 06:55:05 2016-12-14 06:55:05          4       10   6015.033
3  2017-01-24 22:05:24 2017-01-24 22:05:24          2       10  59950.317
4  2017-03-07 19:00:43 2017-03-07 19:00:43          3       10  60295.317
5  2017-03-26 01:55:51 2017-03-26 01:55:51          1       10  26335.133
6  2017-03-26 03:05:51 2017-03-26 03:15:51          5       20     10.000
7  2017-03-26 03:25:51 2017-03-26 03:25:51          2       10     20.000
8  2017-03-26 03:45:51 2017-03-26 03:45:51          6       10     20.000
9  2016-12-02 00:05:27 2016-12-02 00:05:27          2       10         NA
10 2017-02-27 20:10:44 2017-02-27 20:10:44          1       10 126485.283
```

and I want for each row i with `inter` < 100  to put the values of `tend` in the row i-1, to get a weighted (by duration) arithmetic mean of `mean_light` of i and i-1, and to remove the i row from the tab to have something like this:

```
        tfirst            tend             mean_light duration      inter
1  2016-12-10 02:40:03 2016-12-10 02:40:03          2       10         NA
2  2016-12-14 06:55:05 2016-12-14 06:55:05          4       10   6015.033
3  2017-01-24 22:05:24 2017-01-24 22:05:24          2       10  59950.317
4  2017-03-07 19:00:43 2017-03-07 19:00:43          3       10  60295.317
5  2017-03-26 01:55:51 2017-03-26 03:45:51          X       X  26335.133
9  2016-12-02 00:05:27 2016-12-02 00:05:27          2       10         NA
10 2017-02-27 20:10:44 2017-02-27 20:10:44          1       10 126485.283
```

for the moment i've tried this:

```
uni <- which(encounters_MT$inter < 100)

for(i in uni){
    encounters_MT$tend[i-1] <- encounters_MT$tend[i]
    encounters_MT$mean_conductivity[i-1] <- (encounters_MT$mean_conductivity[i-1]*encounters_MT$duration[i-1] + encounters_MT$mean_conductivity[i]*encounters_MT$duration[i]) / (encounters_MT$duration[i] + encounters_MT$duration[i-1])
    encounters_MT <- encounters_MT[-i,]
  }

}
```

but i've this error message:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "tend", value = c(1481334003, 1481694905,  : 
  replacement has 346 rows, data has 344
```

Comment: One problem is that you remove rows while processing on initial row index `uni`.

Comment: Okay but how i'm supposed to avoid that ?

Comment: You could try to process per blocs, there is a bit of work here I won't have time to do it today.

Comment: Why did you tag your question `dplyr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the problem that @cbo brought up by making a new dataframe. Below is an example that could definitely be made more efficient but at least gives you something to go off of.

Here's some fake data I used that I think approximates yours:

```
#looks like the tfirst and tend are the same
tfirst = Sys.time() + rnorm(100, 1000, 100)

df <- data.frame(
  tfirst = tfirst,
  tend = tfirst,
  mean_light = ceiling(runif(100,0,10)),
  duration = sample(seq(10,50, by = 10), 100, replace = T),
  inter = runif(100, 10,200)
)
```

I assume you want this in order of the time the measurement was taken, so I reordered the dataset like that:

```
df <- df[order(df$tfirst), ]
```

I also changed the POSIXct data to character to avoid any `rbind` issues. You can turn them back into date-time objects later.

```
df$tfirst <- as.character(df$tfirst)
df$tend <- as.character(df$tend)
```

You can then either define a dataframe and add rows to it (which is what I do here) or just define a list and use a `do.call(rbind, ls)` at the end. The benefit of the latter is you don't have to define columns.

What you are really wanting to do is update row i based on what is happening at row i+1. If row i+1 has a `inter < 100` than you want to add its data to row i via the arithmetic mean. The loop below reflects this.

```
#create a new dataframe to write into
new.df <- data.frame(tfirst = NA, 
                     tend = NA, 
                     mean_light = NA, duration = NA, inter = NA)

for(i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)){
  row.next1 <- df[i+1,]
  this.row <- df[i,]

  #if this row is less than 100, it should have been dealt 
  # with in the prior loop and we don't want it
  if(this.row$inter<100){
    next
  }
  #if i +1 is less than 100 
  if(row.next1$inter<100){
    new.tfirst <- this.row$tfirst
    new.tend <- row.next1$tend
    #sum of durations
    new.duration <- sum(this.row$duration, row.next1$duration)
    #arithmetic mean of light
    new.mean_light <- sum((this.row$mean_light*this.row$duration), (row.next1$mean_light*row.next1$duration))/new.duration
    new.row <- c(new.tfirst, new.tend, new.mean_light, new.duration, this.row$inter)
    new.df <- rbind(new.df, new.row)
  } else new.df <- rbind(new.df, this.row)
}
```

Again, depending on how big your dataset is, this may not be the best way to go about it, but it gets the job done if its not too many rows.